# Jquery when date change, change another date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I use a Jquery date-picker for a start and end date, what I would like to do is when the user changes the 'start' date, the 'end' date automatically changes to the start date + X days?

What would others suggest the best way of doing this?  I am using GB dates so its `dd/mm/yyyy` so doesn't work out of the box with the JavaScript date object?  am sure this is trivial for a more experienced jQuery folk!

Comment: could you add a bit of your html code .... certainly that is better than to start from scratch

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to bind to the `onSelect` event. See the jQuery docs for it [here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect).

This is probably about what you're looking for.

```
var DAYS = 6; // <-- Or whatever

$('#start_date').datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $('#end_date').setDate(
           (Number(dateText.substr(0,2))+DAYS) + dateText.substr(2)
        )
    },
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
});  

$('#end_date').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
});
```

Comment: ... you are doing funny things with parsing - why not use `$.datepicker.parseDate( format, value, settings )`(http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) and then use an appropriate `.setXX()`-method instead? this would avoid any crucial adaptions, if `dateFormat` changes ... and is more, well, the "correct" way :)

Comment: @Andreas you're totally right about the `parseDate()` thing, but I think I am using the right `.sexXX()` method--`.setDate()`.

Comment: i did not talk about `$.datepicker.setDate()` - i talked about `Date.setXXX()` (sorry for the confusion)

Answer (score 1):

There is an event in the jquery UI Date picker.

Please have a look to: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onSelect